# Create a tree like structure in html/css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a tree like structure in HTML. I'm not an expert HTML programmer and was wondering how do I do the following kind of tree structure in HTML

```
             4
    2                  6

1          3       5          7
```

My question is given some strings/numbers how can I relatively position them in the webpage based on the number of strings. For example in the first line I have only one number, so it should go to middle. In second line I have two numbers so slice the page into three parts and place them on the dividing lines. Please do not suggest any third party libraries etc. I need a pure HTML/JS code to do this.
Thanks

Comment: SO is not a site for providing code snippets my friend. We help you solve a problem that u have tried. So, I suggest, u try out something and when u fail, let us know, we are here to help

Comment: Where are you getting these numbers? Do you just want to display them as text? And, oh yeah, what have you tried?

Comment: These numbers are coming from a balanced binary search tree. My current solution for this is create a grid with logN rows and N columns and place the elements properly to display them as tree. I'm not a web programmer so I thought people have some easier way to do it

Comment: @dramzy N is the number of nodes in the balanced binary search tree

Comment: @LearningNeverStops Yes you are correct but I got one solution for it and I'm trying to find another simple and easy solution to do the same. I thought people with lot of HTML knowledge have a number of ways to do it

Comment: @Sreekar okay, great. So edit your question to show what you had tried. Then people can give a comparisons. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it with a table it would be like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4">4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">2</th>
        <th colspan="2">6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>7</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Code works like charm. you are awesome.  I was doing it the hard way :)

Answer (score 1):

if you mean dropdown trees, this is a good idea:

```html
<details>
  <summary>1</summary>
  1
  <details>
    <summary>2</summary>
    2
    </details>
    <details>
      <summary>3
      </summary>
      3
  </details>
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about this tag. Thanks for sharing!